# Error line inside a package

Tags: errors, tex-core, package-writing

I've created my own package, but, when I use it in a new document, and pdflatex find an error using a custom command (defined in my own package), it shows me only the error line where this command was used (respect to the main file), and not the error line inside the package itself (respect to the package file).

Anybody knows how can I force pdflatex shows me the error line inside the package file (i.e, forcing navigation inside includes or packages)?

Comment: TeX can't do it. It doesn't keep track of files and line numbers when it stores definitions.

Comment: i don't think you can.  once the package is (successfully) processed, all that remains of it is the macros, etc., that it defined.

Comment: A sad issue then ... :(

Comment: If by "line" you mean lines of definition rather than line number in the file then set \errorcontextlines=\maxdimen to get more of the definition context shown in error messages

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would claim this is a natural result of the fact that TeX is a macro language that  works by expansion. As such a definition that you make in your package will not be code that is executed but largely code that expands to other code (possibly from other packages) and so it is not at all clear what you mean by "not the error line inside the package itself (respect to the package file)".

To give you a (fully nonsense) example of this, consider the following code:

```
% this here could be in package A that you loaded or in the kernel
\def\foo !#1!{*#1*}
\def\bar{\foo !test!}

% this here would be in your package
\def\gobbleabit#1#2{#1}
\def\baz { \expandafter \gobbleabit \bar }

% this would be in your document:
\baz
```

now if you run this through TeX (or LaTeX) then you you will get

```
! Use of \foo doesn't match its definition.
\bar ->\foo !t
              est!
l.11 \baz
```

And where is the error? In package "A" where `\foo` and `\bar` was defined, or in your package that defined `\baz` in a way that it gobbled away the "!" needed to execute `\foo`?
I would say the error was in your package.

However, if we alter the example a bit to

```
% this here would be in package A
\def\foo !#1!{*#1*}
\def\bar{\foo test!}

% this here would be in your package

\def\baz { \bar ... }

% this would be in your document:
\baz
```

we will get nearly the same error message:

```
! Use of \foo doesn't match its definition.
\bar ->\foo t
             est!
l.11 \baz
```

but this time the fault is in package A with a wrong definition of `\bar`. Bottom line, the best you can do in such languages is to give a stack trace  which is what TeX does.

If you want to see the full stack trace of all ongoing expansions, set `\errorcontextlines=\maxdimen` and then you will also see all intermediate parts of the stack (and how far TeX has read in each level of expansion), in this case one more:

```
! Use of \foo doesn't match its definition.
\bar ->\foo t
             est!
\baz -> \bar 
             ... 
l.11 \baz
```